# watsonx: using notebook for data collection - how can I save it locally so I can use it for AutoAI?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to store data from yfinance lib locally on watsonx, so I can use it in the AutoAI function.

Right now I have written the following:

```
# Save to CSV
    historical_prices.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
    print(f"Data saved to {output_file}")
# Fetch data and save to CSV
fetch_finance_data(finance_symbols, start_date, end_date, output_file)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I tried looking in FAQ

Comment: "watsonx" is a brand name and has many products. Add details on what you are doing, so at least someone can understand your question